# I am attempting to make a html text extracter but ran into an issue

Tags: python

```
import re
from urllib import request
lines = []
with request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphoria_(American_TV_series)') as fin:
text = fin.read().decode('utf-8')
lines = re.findall(r'<p>.*?</p>', text, re.DOTALL)
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
print(fout.writelines(lines))
```

This code returns none. I have no idea why. I'm attempting to write some code that reads an html file and then extracts the text out of it. thanks in advance and dont hesitate to ask a question if there is something you need to know about the code

Comment: So you want the text on the Wikipedia page?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the text from the Wikipedia page, I recommend using BeautifulSoup to extract by the `<p>` tag instead of using regex.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphoria_(American_TV_series)'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
paragraphs = soup.select('p')

with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        fout.writelines(paragraph.text)
```

**Output:**
[image]